# How to fix this "for loop" what in if statement

Tags: c#, sql-server

I wrote nested if statement. One of them includes a loop. After this loop else statement does not work As if they did not exist. It goes to catch statement.
Although when I cancel this loop, else statement work.

How can I fix it?

This is visual studio and SQL Server 2005. I have tried to save the value what in the text box "txtCategoryName". In the first `if` statement I check that text box is not null. In the second "if statement" I check the value what in the text box duplicate or not. In the `else` statement, I save the value.

```
try
{
   if (txtCategoryName.Text == string.Empty)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Fill the textBox", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);    
      return;
   }
   else if (txtCategoryName.Text != string.Empty)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i <= dgvCategory.Rows.Count; i++)
      {
         if (dgvCategory.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == txtCategoryName.Text)
         {
            MessageBox.Show("Choose another name", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);    
            return;
         }
      }
   }
   else
   {
      txtCategoryId.Text = clsCat.getCategoryId().Rows[0][0].ToString();
      clsCat.addCategory(txtCategoryName.Text);
      MessageBox.Show("Done", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
      txtCategoryId.Clear();
      txtCategoryName.Clear();
      dataPreview();
   }    
}
catch
{
   MessageBox.Show("Erroe save in category", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
   return;
}
```

I expect to save "txtCategoryName.Text" in the database if it pass through the first "if statement" and the second "if statement" to do what in "else statement". But after the loop in the second "if statement" it goes to "catch" directly.

Comment: If you provided your error msg ,it would be fine. I think, your for loop may cause to index out of range exception.pls Debug them. change less than or equal to less than only. & your last else statement is doing nothing, hence maintain outside bool variable to check whether your condition pass or fail. if pass , then insert those value to DB.

Comment: It's the "goes to `catch`" part that will shed light on your problem.  This is the whole point of `try ... catch`, to `try` something and if it `throw`s to `catch` that `Exception` and handle it or report it.  You are just silently swallowing the `Exception` and not reporting its details in your `MessageBox`.  You should change `catch` to `catch (Exception ex)` and display some properties of `ex` in the message box, or inspect `ex` in the debugger.  Very often just knowing the specific type of the `Exception` will point you to offending line, but otherwise the stack trace definitely will.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning solution before building?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add one `isElseLoop` bool variable which will get updated once the `else loop` is executed. Refer the code below.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    bool isElseLoop = false;

    if (txtCategoryName.Text == string.Empty)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Fill the textBox", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
      return;
    }
    else if (txtCategoryName.Text != string.Empty)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < dgvCategory.Rows.Count; i++)
      {
        if (dgvCategory.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == txtCategoryName.Text)
        {
          MessageBox.Show("Choose another name", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
          isElseLoop = true;
          return;
        }
      }
    }

    if (!isElseLoop)
    {
      txtCategoryId.Text = clsCat.getCategoryId().Rows[0][0].ToString();
      clsCat.addCategory(txtCategoryName.Text);
      MessageBox.Show("Done", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
      txtCategoryId.Clear();
      txtCategoryName.Clear();
      dataPreview();
    }
  }
  catch
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Erroe save in category", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is solved. But you forget to change "i <= dgvCategory.Rows.Count" to "i < dgvCategory.Rows.Count". Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in `int i = 0; i <= dgvCategory.Rows.Count; i++` because you are initializing the i with 0 and go through `dgvCategory.Rows.Count`.

It should be `int i = 0; i < dgvCategory.Rows.Count; i++` more specifically `i < dgvCategory.Rows.Count;` instead of `i <= dgvCategory.Rows.Count;`

Comment: Plus one as you explained the problem and didn't post a lump of badly formatted code.

Comment: After change "i < dgvCategory.Rows.Count;" instead of " i <= dgvCategory.Rows.Count;" it does not go to "catch" but it does not go to "else statement" also. Although when i cancel the second "if statement" it works but with the duplication possibility